# Cocoa Touch - Slow Moving CGPointMake

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm using the following code to move an UIImageView across screen. With this code it rockets across the screen but I want it to slowly move. What do I need to do?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slide-up" context:NULL];
        astroid_1.center = CGPointMake(astroidPosX,astroidPosY);  // change this to somewhere else you want.
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the duration of the animation:

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
```